# Download function not working CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, download

I read the documentation regarding file [downloads](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html), however I can't seem to get this to work.

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213983/cakephp-downloadable-pdf-file) [through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745071/cakephp-not-downloading-file) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333399/cakeresponse-download-file-is-not-working) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723605/cakephp-download-function-not-working) as well, and have had no luck.

My function looks as follows:

```
public function generate($id) {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->Magazine->recursive = 2;
    $DistributionLists = $this->Magazine->DistributionList->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Magazine.id' => $id
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'DistributionList.priority ASC'
            )
        )
    );
    $this->set('magazine',$DistributionLists[0]['Magazine']['magazine_name']);
    $this->set(compact('DistributionLists'));
}

public function download() {
    $this->viewClass = 'Media';
    $params = array(
        'id'        => "Magazine Distribution List.doc",
        'name'      => "Magazine Distribution List",
        'download'  => true,
        'extension' => 'doc',
        'path'      => APP . "tmp" . DS
    );
    $this->set($params);
    unlink(APP."tmp".DS);
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
}

public function afterFilter() {
    parent::afterFilter();
    if($this->action == 'generate') {
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'download'));
    }
}
```

The reason I have an `afterFilter` function is because the word document that needs to be downloaded is created in the view file.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: You probably have to remove the redirect in your download method.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What is/isn't happening?...etc

Comment: @ndm, sorry, CakePHP 2.2

Comment: @Dave, didn't get any errors.

Comment: @dhofstet Please put that as an answer. Funny enough that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the call to the `redirect` method in your `download` method because it prevents your view from getting "rendered" due to the redirect.